# online users in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

i want to obtain count of online users in sharepoint 2007 website. how i can do it?

Comment: Hi, i have posted the same question by mistake :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094817/get-sharepoint-online-users.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
I think there is only one way to get the number of online users.
You have to save the last activity of each user, and when you want to know the number of users online you search for all users that they have the date of now minus their last activity date is less then session timeout.