# Get Sharepoint Online users

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How Can i get the number of online users in sharepoint 2007?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extensive explanation, tutorial, etc.: [Find Number of Users Currently Logged on to a SharePoint Site](http://blog.furuknap.net/find-number-of-users-currently-logged-on-to-a-sharepoint-site)

The gist of it is that you don't have OOTB features to show you the number of currently logged in users. You can check IIS for current users, but you don't know whether these are logged on or not. The solution explained in the blog article is to create a delegate control which resides on all pages which counts the number of current sessions. You still don't really have a "live" view as the web is pretty much stateless and it is hard to know whether a user e.g. closed the browser or switched to another tab.

Comment: Is it a good idea to do the same Principe in httpModule not using delegateControl?

Comment: I don't see a reason why you shouldn't.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

Out of Box i don't think their is any support their is utility available with share point boost [Site user directory](http://www.boostsolutions.com/site-user-directory.html)

Else you can create a custom web part and attach it to the master page to keep track of how many users or online currently